# Has no method parseJSON with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.filter_users').live('click', function() {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
            alert( obj.name === "John" );
        });
});
```

In the moment I'm clicking the class `filter_users` (It's a simple checkbox..) It shows me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)}
>   has no method 'parseJSON'

Why does it happen? The jQuery file is from here - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js

Other jQuery elements work well.

Comment: I have always used jQuery.parseJSON and it was working well.

Comment: Have you got any plugins running/

Comment: This code work in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/ZGbd7/

Comment: Well... have you tried another jQuery file.... just in case?

Comment: I tried another jQuery file and it doesn't work..

Comment: @Baszz JSON.parse() won't work in IE6&7

Comment: The [`.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) was added to jQuery only at version 1.4.1 so it means you probably use older version. I guess that you include both old version and new version, and since the old version is included later it "overrides" the new version.

Comment: Cheers, added this also as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) was added to jQuery only at version 1.4.1 so it means you probably use older version.

Good chance that you include both old version and new version, and since the old version is included later it "overrides" the new version.

Include *only* the new version and it will work.

Comment: For those who need it in older versions, I found success with [this replacement](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js) from Douglas Crockford on Github.